# ReactNative recyclerlistview Space between items is increasing or overlapping

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, recyclerlistview

I am working on android application using ReactNative RecyclerListView For displaying list of items in my app. Please check my recyclerlistview code in render function.

```
<RecyclerListView rowRenderer={_renderRow} dataProvider={_dataProvider}
        layoutProvider={_layoutProvider}
        canChangeSize={true}
        forceNonDeterministicRendering={true}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => String(index)}
        extraData={selectedItem}/>
```

And following is the _layoutProvider logic.

```
const _layoutProvider = new LayoutProvider((i) => {
    return _dataProvider.getDataForIndex(i)._id;
  }, (_id, dim) => {

    dim.width = width;
    dim.height = height / 1.7;
  });
  _renderRow.bind(this);
```

If i used fixed height, The UI display is not same in all resolutions. I have used **forceNonDeterministicRendering** attribute. But the problem is when i am going from this screen and coming back to this screen, Item gap is getting increased. If i reduce height in layoutProvider, bottom of the item is overlapping by next item. Please check the screenshots for reference.

[image: Space is increased between two items] When first time rendering its working good without any issues. Please help me to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance..